# Datagridview date format issue

Tags: vb.net

I am having a problem that my date of birth in datagridview is show the default time 12am,
however my access date type of "dateofbirth" is set for only "Short Date"

How can I just only show the date of birth in short date in datagridview?

[image]

Here is my datagridview coding.

```
    Public Sub LoadDGV()
    Dim SqlQuery As String = "Select * from userss where delete = no"
    Dim SqlCommand As New OleDbCommand
    Dim SqlAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim table As New DataTable

    With SqlCommand
        .CommandText = SqlQuery
        .Connection = conn
    End With

    With SqlAdapter
        .SelectCommand = SqlCommand
        .Fill(table)
    End With

    DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
    For i = 0 To table.Rows.Count - 1
        With DataGridView1
            .Rows.Add(table.Rows(i)("studentID"), table.Rows(i)("full_name"), table.Rows(i)("password"), table.Rows(i)("course"), table.Rows(i)("dateofbirth"), table.Rows(i)("gender"), table.Rows(i)("imail_address"), table.Rows(i)("tel_no"), table.Rows(i)("handphone_no"))
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [DefaultCellStyle.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/f9x2790s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). "d" will give you the shortdatetime format

```
MyDatagridview.Columns("columnName").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "d"
```

Here and are some [Standard formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) formatting strings.

Comment: columnName is according to the header text?
and the "d" is?

Comment: No, column name and header text are different properties. You can also use the zero-based index for the column, so it would be 4 in your example. MyDatagridview.Columns(4).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "d"

Comment: Oh, I got it and worked perfectly, thank you very much, now I learned 2 different coding :D

Comment: Is that any methods to change the button's picture in datagridview?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
table.Rows(i)("dateofbirth")
```

You can use

```
table.Rows(i)("dateofbirth").ToShortDateString
```

Comment: Is that any methods to change the button's picture in datagridview?